# Как сделать поиск по организациям в Яндекс.Картах?

Tags: javascript, массивы, yandex-maps-api

Если набрать в поиске Яндекса "Психологические центры", будет показана карта со всеми похожими организациями, и карта уже настроена на твоё местоположение.
Скажите, как я могу вывести такую же карту через API. За 2 дня так и не понял. Насколько я понял, нужна команда `geocode`, но тогда показываются организации, именно включающие эти слова в своё название.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте свой код.

Answer (score 1):

В API есть поиск по организациям. [Пример в песочнице Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo?from=SO)

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.74, 37.58],
    zoom: 13,
    controls: []
  });

  // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
  // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
  var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
      provider: 'yandex#search'
    }
  });

  myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

  // Программно выполним поиск определённых кафе в текущей
  // прямоугольной области карты.
  searchControl.search('Психологические центры');
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```